# gzopen throwing exception for existing, valid file

Tags: php, zlib

I am trying to build a log parser using the zLib functions, and am running into a problem. This is my code:

```
$filename = '/Users/awallace/AccessLogs/access.log.6.gz';

$handle = gzopen( $filename, 'r');

while ( $buffer = gzgets( $handle, 2048 ) )
{
    if ( strpos($buffer, "Leadbuilder.") !== false )
    {
        print $buffer . "\n";
    }

    gzclose($handle);
}
```

(I have removed error checking code). WhenI run this, I get a warning:

```
 Warning: gzgets(): 5 is not a valid stream resource in /Users/awallace/test.php on line 22
```

If I dump out the handle after gzopen, I get: "Resource id #5". Any idea why this isn't working?

- PHP v:5.5.29
- MacOS 10.10.5
- Ouput of "file" command:

  > /Users/awallace/AccessLogs/access.log.6.gz: gzip compressed data, from
  >   Unix, last modified: Wed Feb 24 23:35:20 2016

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You close the handle inside your loop, so on the second loop iteration `$handle` is invalid.

Instead do this:

```
$handle = gzopen( $filename, 'r');        
while ( !gzeof($handle) )
{
    $buffer = gzgets( $handle, 2048 );

    if ( strpos($buffer, "Leadbuilder.") !== false )
    {
        print $buffer . "\n";
    }
}
gzclose($handle);
```